# Distributed lock using redisson- quorum configuration and selecting a new master node in case of old master failure

Tags: redisson, distributed-lock

Distributed lock using redisson- Configure quorum configuration and acquiring lock from majority of nodes
Configuration guide where can we find or some examples

Answer (score 0):

RedLock algorithm was deprecated due to issues described here https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html

Consider to [FencedLock](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/8.-distributed-locks-and-synchronizers/#810-fenced-lock)